# Inheritable only inside assembly in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

In C# Is there way to specify a class to be inherited only by a class present in the same assembly and for other assemblies should behave like a public sealed type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think Eric Lippert gets the defining quotes here:

- [Preventing third-party derivation part one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/preventing-third-party-derivation-part-one)
- [Preventing third-party derivation part two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/preventing-third-party-derivation-part-two)

Answer (score 16):

The language itself doesn't have anything that makes this easy, but you should be able to do this by making your constructors internal.  If you do this, however, you won't be able to new it up from external assemblies, so you'll have to add a factory method.

```
public class Foo
{
    internal Foo()
    {
    }

    public Foo Create()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Here's an alternative that lets you new up the class in external assemblies

```
public sealed class Foo : FooBase
{

}

public class FooBase
{
    internal FooBase() { }
}
```

One question you might ask yourself, however, is exactly *why* you want the class to be sealed.  Sometimes it's inevitable, but I have seen the `sealed` keyword get abused so often that I thought I'd bring it up.  Often, developers will seal classes because they are overprotective of their code.  *Most of the time*, if a class is well designed, it doesn't need to be sealed.

Comment: +1 - For your thoughts. But the problem is I need it for ConfigurationElementCollection so, I don't think constructor cannot be made internal in my case

Comment: Try the second solution, create a base class that has internal constructors, and then implement it with a sealed class that has public constructors.

Answer (score 5):

If your class is abstract, there's a very simple way to do it:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    internal abstract void DoNothing();
    // ... other members
}
```

Now although your class and most members are public, the internal abstract member makes it impossible to derive from the class outside your assembly.

Comment: I would suggest naming the method `PreventExternalInheritance` or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question 10 years later (I was searching for this same solution, so I figure it'd be useful to write down in case anybody else has the same problem in the future), the issue has since been addressed natively (albeit indirectly), with the "[private protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected)" access modifier, introduced in C# 7.2.

This modifier only allows access if it is within the same assembly, and derived from the base class. Apply it to the constructor, and it cannot be derived outside the current assembly. An aside, if you can get away with "internal" and/or metadata, do it, as this requires C# 7.2, which may break compatibility with older devices or applications. Also note that the error produced by this (cannot access constructor due to protection level) is not the same as you would get trying to derive a sealed class (cannot derive a sealed class), but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with language constructs, but try with reflection

```
public class MyClass{
  public MyClass(){
    if(this.GetType().Assembly != typeof(MyClass).Assembly){
        throw new Exception("Can't derive from this type!");
  }
}
```

Checked it up. Seems to be working. The only problem is that unless somebody reads documentation, the trouble is known at runtime.

Comment: It would be nice if you could flag it with some sort of attribute, like you do with obsolete code.

Comment: Well, you can always add to <summary> comment: "This class cannot be inherited."

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think would be to use a public wrapper on an internal class, probably with a common interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

internal class Foo : IFoo
{
}

public sealed class PublicFoo : IFoo
{
    private Foo m_Foo = new Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I've found another way that works really good and I wanted to post it for other people.

1. Make a base class with an internal constructor.
2. Make your derived classes inherit from the base class and be sealed.

````

```
public abstract class LockResult {
    internal LockResult() {

    }
}

public sealed class LockSucceededResult : LockResult {
    //Info for when a lock succeeded
}

public sealed class LockFailedResult : LockResult {
    //Info for when a lock failed
}
```

````

Comment: @Michael answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/630308/30594) provides the same solution

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such provision in the C# language itself. However, workarounds -- as suggested by others here -- may suffice.

Comment: It is technically correct, but I suspect that Ramesh probably already intuited that.  It's more helpful to provide potential workarounds.